# Increment OIDs dynamically at SNMP agent

Tags: python-2.7, snmp, pysnmp

I have written the SNMP agent code by configuring two different context names at the SnmpContext class instance. It will register a MIB tree under particular contextName like below,

```
class Test():
    def readVars (self , varBinds, acInfo=(None, None)):
            retItem = []
            for ov in varBinds:
                if str(ov[0]) == '1.3.6.1.4.1.26262.1.1.1.0':
                    retItem.extend([(ov[0], v2c.OctetString('%s' % 'value1'))])
                elif str(ov[0]) == '1.3.6.1.4.1.26262.1.1.2.0':
                    retItem.extend([(ov[0], v2c.OctetString('%s' % 'value2'))])
                . 
                .
                .
            return retItem

    def readNextVars (self , varBinds, acInfo=(None, None)):
            retItem = []
            for ov in varBinds:
                if str(ov[0]) == '1.3.6.1.4.1.26262.1.1.1.0':
                    retItem.extend([('1.3.6.1.4.1.26262.1.1.2.0', v2c.OctetString('%s' %  'value2'))])
                elif str(ov[0]) == '1.3.6.1.4.1.26262.1.1.2.0':
                    retItem.extend([('1.3.6.1.4.1.26262.1.1.3.1.1.0', v2c.OctetString('%s' % 'value3'))])
                .
                .
                .
                .
            else:
                    retItem.extend([('1.3.6.1.4.1.26262.1.1.1.0', v2c.OctetString('%s' % 'value1'))])
            return retItem


mibTreeA = Test()
snmpContext.registerContextName(v2c.OctetString('context-a'), mibTreeA)
snmpContext.registerContextName(v2c.OctetString('context-b'), mibTreeA)
```

As in the example [sample](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v3arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/agent-side-mib-implementations.html)

Here next OID is returned by checking condition using if statement. But I have multiple OIDs and incrementing that using the if statement would be painful.

So I would like to know is there a way to increment the OIDs dynamically? Any example script will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

May be an alternative approach could be to have a [dict](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/pysnmp/smi/indices.py#L110) of OID-value pairs (where value can be a callable), then `.nextKey` method would do the increment part?

In other words, may be all those `if` conditions could be folded into some ordered data structure supporting essentially two operations:

- get the next item
- get the value associated with an item